# Bash script passing string argument containing $

Tags: string, bash, argument-passing

I need to pass a string argument to a bash script that may contain a $ character. I don't want to force a \ to be inserted into the string outside of the script.

I tried to do that within the script, but couldn't figure out how to do this.

I had a similar issue at a later point in the script where I read in a string using "read". I could only get it to work by forcing the user to enter \$, which is not going to work for my application.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please explain or give some sample in how `yourscript.sh` is run, how are arguments passed and which kind of form.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to have to escape the `$` with a backslash, then the only other alternative is to surround the argument in **single quotes**. It's not possible to pass a 'naked' `$` into your script because the shell will try to expand it. Using single quotes prevents shell expansion and will preserve the `$`.

For example:

```
myscript.sh '$foo'
```

Comment: just to clarify: "it's not possible to pass a naked $, because the shell will expand it" really means, that the parent shell (where you run your script and provide arguments) will do the expansion. your script (running in a separate shell, which could be different from the parent shell) will never see the $args .

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So to use this technique I guess I would write a small parent script in another shell type that won't expand the $, and then call my bash script with ' chars around my string. I'll give that a shot.